# Android M Permissions: onRequestPermissionsResult() not being called in custom button class

Tags: android, runtime, android-6.0-marshmallow, user-permissions

I have one Custom button class in which I have requested CALL_PHONE permission on button click.Everything is fine but I am not getting the user result in onRequestPermissionResult().Below here I am posting my custom button class.

```
public class CustomCallExecutiveButton extends Button implements View.OnClickListener, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

Context mContext;
private Button mCallButton;
private int REQUEST_CALL = 1;

public CustomCallExecutiveButton(Context context) {

    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    init();
}

public CustomCallExecutiveButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;
    init();
}

public CustomCallExecutiveButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    mContext = context;
    init();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public CustomCallExecutiveButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    mContext = context;
    init();
}


private void init() {
    setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    CheckCallPermission();


}
public void CheckCallPermission() {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestCameraPermission();
    } else {
        intentToCall();
    }
}

public void intentToCall() {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "9069118117"));
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    mContext.startActivity(callIntent);
}

public void requestCameraPermission() {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) mContext,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
        openCallPermissionDailog();

    } else {
        openCallPermissionDailog();
    }
}

public void openCallPermissionDailog() {

    //Requesting camera and storage permission dailog
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    alert.setTitle("Permission");
    alert.setMessage("Phone State Permission Needed To Make Call.");
    alert.setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //when user clicks on yes onRequestPermissionResult tells whether user granted permission or not.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                    REQUEST_CALL);
        }
    });

    alert.show();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CALL) {

        if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Camera permission has been granted, preview can be displayed
            intentToCall();
        }


    }

}
}
```

Thanks in advance folks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not getting the user result in onRequestPermissionResult()

Yes, you are. It is going to the `onRequestPermissionResult()` of whatever activity is represented by `mContext`.

IMHO, what you are doing is a violation of separation-of-concerns. Something that is more of a controller, such as an activity or fragment, is responsible for checking and requesting permissions, not a view.

That being said, you are welcome to have the activity forward the `onRequestPermissionResult()` results to the view, if you wish to keep more of your existing code.

Comment: That means I cant get result in my custom class.I need to implement onRequestPermissionResult in all activities in which I am using my custom class.